# Is there a way to change a .iso files volume id from the command line?

Tags: linux, iso, disk-image

I have a `.iso` file under linux and have been trying to find a way to change the volume id without having to recreate the `.iso` file. Most of the authoring tools such as `mkisofs` provide a switch for setting the volume `(-V)` for example. However I can't figure out how to change it on a pre-existing `.iso` file.

For clarification, the bit I'm trying to change is this `Volume id:` string. Here's an example dump from the isoinfo command.

```
% isoinfo -d -i /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso 
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: Win32
Volume id: VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.8_75467
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: 
Application id: MKISOFS ISO 9660/HFS FILESYSTEM BUILDER & CDRECORD CD-R/DVD CREATOR (C) 1993 E.YOUNGDALE (C) 1997 J.PEARSON/J.SCHILLING
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 22203
Joliet with UCS level 3 found
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Volume ID is always stored at offset 0x8028 as 32 byte ASCII string. Edit it in place.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Use: $0 <iso_file> <new volume id>\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
open my $file, "+<", $ARGV[0] or die "Cannot open: $!";
seek $file, 0x8028,0;
printf $file "%-32.32s", uc($ARGV[1]);
```

Test - (isovolid.pl is a name of the above script):

```
$ genisoimage -V A123456798012345678901234567890X -o aaa.iso *
$ isoinfo -d -i aaa.iso | grep 'Volume id:'
Volume id: A123456798012345678901234567890X
$ ./isovolid.pl aaa.iso NEWVOLUMEID
$ isoinfo -d -i aaa.iso | grep 'Volume id:'
Volume id: NEWVOLUMEID
```

Comment: I would like to add that in case the ISO additionally contains a Joliet filesystem the volume id may be used from that one. In my case it was stored at offset 0x8828 in UTF-16. I added the following two lines to change that id too: seek $file, 0x8828,0;
binmode($file, ":encoding(utf-16be)");
printf $file "%-16.16s", uc($ARGV[1]);

Answer (score 4):

xorriso can do this:

```
$ xorriso -dev ./VBoxGuestAdditions.iso -volid 'YourLable' -commit
xorriso 1.4.6 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

xorriso : NOTE : Loading ISO image tree from LBA 0
xorriso : UPDATE : 32 nodes read in 1 seconds
Drive current: -dev './VBoxGuestAdditions.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is written , is appendable
Media summary: 1 session, 29111 data blocks, 56.9m data, 20.3g free
Volume id    : 'VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.34_121010'
xorriso : WARNING : -volid text does not comply to ISO 9660 / ECMA 119 rules
ISO image produced: 27 sectors
Written to medium : 192 sectors at LBA 29120
Writing to './VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' completed successfully.

xorriso : NOTE : Re-assessing -outdev './VBoxGuestAdditions.iso'
xorriso : NOTE : Loading ISO image tree from LBA 0
xorriso : UPDATE : 32 nodes read in 1 seconds
Drive current: -dev './VBoxGuestAdditions.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is written , is appendable
Media summary: 1 session, 29147 data blocks, 56.9m data, 20.3g free
Volume id    : 'YourLable'
$
```